# How to run Node app locally from Github repo?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express, build

I want to run this https://github.com/supernoir/heroines-of-science locally.

I did the following steps

- Cloned the app locally
- Then did `npm install` to download all the dependencies
- Opened the app folder and executed `node server.js`

But getting Cannot Get / when opened the webpage.

Any help would be helpful.

Comment: open the app folder first and then run `npm install` , then you can excecute

Comment: @Nithin-Techidiots Tried but didn't work

Comment: There is no "/" route in `server.js` file, try "/heroines" instead.

Comment: `app.get('/heroines', function(request, response) {` here you have /heroines if it is home page you can remove this and make `app.get('/', function(request, response) {` check this out..